# How can I allow buttons in Android development to scale without changing their shape?

Tags: android-studio, vector-graphics, nine-patch

Say we got this button in a layout file, say `app/res/layout/activity_main.xml`:

```xml
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        android:text="ok" />
```

Also say that `@drawable/test` is an SVG file (vector image) that gives a unique shape for the button as follows:

[image]

The problem that I have is that when the text `android:text="sadfsdafsadfsadfsadfsdfsdafsdf"` is long, the button's shape gets ruined as follows:

[image]

As the button is stretched horizontally, I want *only* to stretch the button from the middle, without harming its shape on the sides.

This is the desired outcome (trying to achieve it, but so far it failed):

[image]

I heard of [9-patch files](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch), but sadly they only work for bitmaps.   About vector files: how can we maintain their shapes when scaled?

Comment: I'm not fully aware of the UI but did you tried restricting button's maximum length like this?
android:maxLength="5"

Comment: @SreehariK - I want the button to span for as wide as the phone is.  In portrait mode, it will span the entire span.  So limiting button's width contradicts my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there isn't any direct way to achieve this without using a 9-patch. Either you will need to make the head and tail portion for the button into a different views if and only if you need to use a vector.

I suggest to make a PNG copy of this vector and use 9 patch of it. If you're concerned about the size, then it won't cost much for 9-patch images.

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved by trimming stroked path on your vector drawable.

More information is in *[Trimming stroked paths](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/11/introduction-to-icon-animation-techniques.html#trimming-stroked-paths)*.

Example:

```xml
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector
            android:name="vector"
            android:width="500dp"
            android:height="500dp"
            android:viewportWidth="500"
            android:viewportHeight="500">
            <path
                android:name="path"
                android:pathData="M 120 80 L 160 120 L 120 160 L 160 160 L 160 80 L 120 80"
                android:fillColor="#31a8f7"
                android:strokeColor="#31a8f7"
                android:strokeWidth="1"/>
            <path
                android:name="path_1"
                android:pathData="M 320 120 L 160 120"
                android:strokeColor="#31a8f7"
                android:strokeWidth="81"/>
            <path
                android:name="path_2"
                android:pathData="M 320 160 L 360 120 L 320 80 Z"
                android:fillColor="#31a8f7"
                android:strokeColor="#31a8f7"
                android:strokeWidth="1"/>
        </vector>
    </aapt:attr>
    <target android:name="path_1">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="trimPathStart"
                    android:duration="150"
                    android:valueFrom="0.6"
                    android:valueTo="0"
                    android:valueType="floatType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="trimPathStart"
                    android:startOffset="150"
                    android:duration="150"
                    android:valueFrom="0"
                    android:valueTo="0.6"
                    android:valueType="floatType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_2">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:duration="150"
                    android:valueFrom="M 220 160 L 260 120 L 220 80 Z"
                    android:valueTo="M 320 160 L 360 120 L 320 80 Z"
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:startOffset="150"
                    android:duration="150"
                    android:valueFrom="M 320 160 L 360 120 L 320 80 Z"
                    android:valueTo="M 220 160 L 260 120 L 220 80 Z"
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```

Comment: Could you add an example for this [vector drawable](https://pastebin.com/Yw3LfD3x)?  I tried something but failed, and not sure if I understood of if this applies.  It seems to me that this feature deletes portions of the vector image.  Not sure how it helps.

Comment: Added an example.
It's made as animation in https://shapeshifter.design/ just as simple POC.

Comment: Thanks, but how to use it?  I used it as a background image, and I got [this weird result](https://i.imgur.com/nfDSo0N.png).  Note how the text "OK" is elsewhere, and the button is so massive and scaled out of whack.

Comment: OK.
First of all, the text is elsewhere because (probably) you took my example vector which has random range viewport and just added your text - position of text cannot match like that. Secondly you have to notice that my vector has three paths for different parts of the image. You have to modify properties for two of them - using trimPathStart and for scaling middle part and pathData for changing position last part like in my animation example - to make it all work correctly.